# Map joysticks to specific USB ports in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, game-controller

I'm working on a Linux (fedora) based arcade dance machine using a game called Stepmania. I've got it all up and running and I'm trying to get it to work with two dance pads.

It detects the dance pads fine and they work well, the only issue is that when the machine is turned on it seems to randomly pick which pad is /dev/input/js0 and which is /dev/input/js1

What this leads to is the pad on the left controlling the character on the right & vice-versa. So I was wondering if there is any way to tie or map the joystick to a particular USB port so they always stay where they should? Or is there another way this could be accomplished ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find some help over at LinuxQuestions.org, link to the answer is:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/possible-to-map-joysticks-to-specific-usb-ports-844793/